# Microsoft Excel - Functions sum values after mulitplying multiple criterias after looking up tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

have provided a link to the excel worksheet that I need to resolve. I have worked up for two values in cell B9, which I need to do for other criteria which goes beyond 18 or so.
Formula that I used is very lengthy and might lead to mistakes.  I want to make this as template so in future when I just insert the values for each employee it should give me the summed up value.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxs1msqwuup4i8n/SuperUser.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this **array formula****:

`=SUM(INDEX(F12:F15,N(IF(1,MATCH(D3:U3,E12:E15))))*D3:U3)`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: The above formula multiplied all values D3:U3 by a single value F12:F15.  The requirement is that lookup the combined criteria D1:U1 & D2:U2 with the tables below and choose appropriate column's value to be multiplied by values in D3:U3.  Example is specified in cell B9 of the excel sheet.

Comment: Not true. The formula I gave first determines the appropriate value from F2:F15 by matching each of the values in the range E2:E15, which is precisely what your short example was doing. It just so happens that, with the current data you are using, the result of every single one of these matches results in a value of 1.3, since every single one of your values in D3:U3 is between 0 and 9999. Also, the example you gave gave no indication that the values in D1:U1 were to be considered. If this is the case, you will need to reformat the 4 tables you are using (for ATT, STT, etc.) into a single one.